# "wait for no man" or "waits for no man" -- subject being "time and tide"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which is the correct usage?

> Time and tide wait for no man.

or

> Time and tide waits for no man.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95513/time-and-tide-wait-for-no-man

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct. The third person plural form of the verb 'to wait' is 'wait'.

If you were talking about tide only you could use the third person singular form, 'waits'

> Tide waits for no man.

But in this case the subject of the sentence is 'time and tide', which is plural. To verify this you can substitute the third person plural pronoun 'they'.

> They wait for no man.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence says that two different things do not wait so the plural form of verb is correct:

> Time and tide wait for no man

is grammatically correct. Etymologically, however, you are correct to wonder. "Zeit," Germanic for "time," is obviously related to the English root for "tide."